# How to scrape the next page without pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, pagination

This link "https://www.muscleandstrength.com/store/promos.html" will redirect you to a site which will show you the list of all their 600+ discounted items. My goal is to scrape them all. But the main problem I am encountering is that it doesn't have the regular pagination with numbers on it (Ex: prev 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... next) or GET url that I can use to retrieve the next page. I have to click the "View Next 20 More Products" to display the next batch. I have no problem scraping a website with pagination on it, but this one is giving me an headache.

Below link is the main JS that is being triggered whenever the next button is being clicked

https://cdn.muscleandstrength.com/store/media/js/ec00de517e571209f780e1b62a3967fd-1534086933.js

In it you will find a line like this:

```
e.post("www.muscleandstrength.com/store/promos/index/filter",{filter:JSON.stringify(t)}
```

If you go to this link "www.muscleandstrength.com/store/promos/index/filter", and scroll all the way down to the bottom, you will discover something like this.

```
filters":{"classfilter":{"lowprice":125,"b1g1":123,"twopacks":119,"couponcode":118,"b1g50":79,"bxgy":36,"b2g1":16},"brandfilter":{"78":77,"84":45,"190":37,"383":26,"120":24,"82":23,"108":22,"42":21,"30":18,"150":18,"133":16,"151":14,"489":14,"490":13,"69":12,"65":11,"369":10,"193":9,"232":9,"53":8,"335":8,"81":7,"93":7,"426":7,"471":7,"67":6,"106":6,"423":6,"43":5,"98":5,"241":5,"267":5,"274":5,"432":5,"481":5,"493":5,"59":4,"64":4,"144":4,"279":4,"292":4,"389":4,"109":3,"183":3,"223":3,"330":3,"421":3,"444":3,"523":3,"76":2,"97":2,"111":2,"132":2,"147":2,"191":2,"196":2,"244":2,"331":2,"344":2,"346":2,"403":2,"406":2,"428":2,"435":2,"38":1,"46":1,"48":1,"51":1,"68":1,"92":1,"116":1,"139":1,"189":1,"194":1,"252":1,"302":1,"303":1,"322":1,"326":1,"380":1,"424":1,"439":1,"450":1,"472":1},"categoryfilter":{"21":119,"9":112,"13":97,"582":76,"57":75,"408":64,"29":62,"130":49,"26":45,"605":45,"58":42,"12":35,"10":34,"140":34,"131":29,"469":29,"44":28,"177":25,"670":25,"55":24,"580":23,"597":23,"22":22,"17":21,"27":21,"40":21,"464":21,"667":21,"28":19,"87":19,"219":19,"452":18,"441":17,"635":16,"684":16,"25":14,"42":14,"544":14,"694":14,"88":13,"132":13,"695":13,"220":12,"562":12,"147":11,"205":11,"53":10,"154":10,"389":10,"423":10,"425":10,"617":10,"51":9,"530":9,"623":9,"686":9,"16":8,"19":8,"86":8,"304":8,"492":8,"554":8,"592":8,"638":8,"52":7,"122":7,"378":7,"410":7,"509":7,"572":7,"594":7,"637":7,"83":6,"171":6,"180":6,"303":6,"409":6,"496":6,"559":6,"666":6,"59":5,"84":5,"142":5,"172":5,"187":5,"302":5,"390":5,"391":5,"400":5,"431":5,"466":5,"512":5,"583":5,"593":5,"632":5,"653":5,"690":5,"696":5,"20":4,"56":4}},"num_results":616}
```

I think it is what's responsible to display the next batch items.

My main question is, what is the easiest way to scrape all these items regardless of the fact that it does not have regular pagination or GET url that I can use to go to the next page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the webpage https://www.muscleandstrength.com/store/promos.html in a browser (I used Chrome). Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open Developer Tools. Go to Network Tab. Here you can see all logged requests. If you click on "View Next 20 Products" on the webpage then the new one request will be logged. Filter XHR requests. The necessary data to retrieve all products you can find in Headers, it looks for me as follows:

[image: request]

To retrieve all products you need just set total quantity to `"limit"`, and 0 to `"offset"` parameters within filter, replay the same XHR and parse response. In  Preview you can find that the response actually is JSON, and the HTML content to be parsed is located in `content` property:

[image: response]

Here is the example showing how that could be done. Go to Console Tab. Copy the below code, paste it in the console and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```js
(function () {
    // retrieve all products
    var count = document.querySelector("span.search-result-available-count").innerText;
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest;
    x.open("POST","https://www.muscleandstrength.com/store/promos/index/filter",false);
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    x.send("filter=%7B%22order%22%3A%22sort_order+desc%2Csales_ranking+asc%22%2C%22brandfilter%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22categoryfilter%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22classfilter%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22limit%22%3A"+count+"%2C%22offset%22%3A0%7D");
    // replace body content with received data
    document.body.innerHTML = JSON.parse(x.responseText).content;
    // create table for output
    var addCell = function(htmlContent) {
        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = htmlContent;
    };
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    document.body.appendChild(table);
    table.style = 'margin:10px;'
    // add table header and body
    var tHead = table.createTHead();
    var row = tHead.insertRow(-1);
    ["#","Product","Price","Rating","Reviews"].forEach(addCell);
    var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");
    table.appendChild(tBody);
    // parse each product
    var products = document.querySelectorAll("li.grid-product");
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        var product = products[i];
        // add row
        row = tBody.insertRow(-1);
        addCell(i+1);
        // parse name
        var m = product.querySelector("a.product-name").innerText.trim();
        addCell(m);
        // parse price
        var m = product.querySelector("div.product-price").innerText.trim();
        addCell(m);
        // parse rating
        var m = product.querySelector("a.star-rating span").style.width;
        addCell(m);
        // parse reviews
        var m = product.querySelector("span.review-count")?.innerText.replace(/\D/g,"") || '0';
        addCell(m);
    }
    // remove unnecessary content
    document.querySelector("div.promo-products").remove();
})();
```

Request is synchronous, so you need to wait until completing for a while. Finally all products are parsed into table, the output for me is as follows:

[image: output]

Comment: You are god damn genius! But the problem here is that I have to copy and paste that code in console every time I need to scrape the page. Is there anyway to do this automatically so that I would just need to run the code in one go and display the item so that I can insert each item one by one on my table?

Comment: @user1995927 That might be done using e. g. WSH JScript or VBScript file, or Excel VBA macro, etc. (the code may be easily converted to VB and other languages). For further help please edit the question and specify 1) where you prefer to store the code, 2) what is the expected output, and 3) how often do you want to scrape the webpage, is there any schedule?

Comment: Sorry! You are right, I should have specified how I want scrape the page. Basically, I use simplehtmldom to scrape the page, so I am used to running my own page to scrape a website.  My goal is to run my own page and scrape these items, the way you did it was perfect except I need to copy and paste the code. I need it to first display these items on my page automatically.

Comment: Also, sorry I am not familiar with WSH JScript or VBScript file, or Excel VBA macro. I only use simplehtmldom to scrape a website.

Comment: Nevermind! This code works like a charm! I just need to allow cross-domain request. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution to loading the DOM.
This loop function will click that view more button for you in a loop until it is finished. You will need some conditions to check for completion and then run your scraper function.

It takes the total number of products, removes the first 60 (already displayed)
  divides that by 20 (the number of products loaded when the view more button is clicked)
  creates a function that scrolls to the bottom of the page with a 2 second timeout for each scroll.

```
var prodElm = document.getElementsByClassName("search-result-available-count")[0].innerText;

var products = parseInt(prodElm.replace(/\D+/g, ''));

var numScrollEventsNeeded = Math.round((products - 60) / 20);

function timedScroller(num) {

  setTimeout(() => {

    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);

    document.getElementsByClassName("view-more btn btn-blue")[0].click();

  }, num);

}

for (i = 0; i < numScrollEventsNeeded; i++) {

  timedScroller(i * 2000);

}
```

Comment: Don't you think this is inefficient way to scrape the page? What if there are let's say 10,000 items that I need to scrape, you will need to constantly click the view more button until all 10,000 items are being displayed before you scrape them? That would take a lot of time and a lot of memory too don't you think? But this is not a bad idea though, I've never thought about it. Thanks!

Comment: Plus the view more button stops working whenever I try to scrape it. So my only option is to find out how its pagination works.

Comment: Indeed, this is not likely a viable option if you need to load more than a thousand or so items. I use this function to load items on the order of 100. 
I will probably be using omegastripes' method in the future.